# Android Studio 4.1.1 - Unable to load class 'javax.annotation.Generated'

Tags: android, android-studio, java-11

First of all, I am new to mobile apps dev. Since recently when android devs need to point to api level 31, I get this error when trying to build:

Unable to load class 'javax.annotation.Generated'.

I updated the JDK to 11, and can't find any resolution to this issue.

I did add this into dependencies:

implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'

But I still get the same error.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update to latest
JDK
version

Add below dependency and try to run :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```